# Messagebox Click not working C#

Tags: c#, dialog, modal-dialog, messagebox

I have a click event as shown below. On click, the Messagebox shows up as expected...But, on Clicking "OK" in the Messagebox, the Messagebox does not close. On Clicking "X" (close) button in the Messagebox window, it closes up as expected.

Observation :  MessageBox Works properly if placed just before "For Loop" is run.

```
 private void Icon_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e, Panel iconPanel)
  {
        if (iconPanel.Name == "Logout")
          {
             MessageBox.Show("Logout");
          }
  }

  public static List<String> ProjectDomains = new List<String>();
  ProjectDomains.Add("Logout");
  ProjectDomains.Add("Designers");
  ProjectDomains.Add("Animators");

foreach (var domain in ProjectDomains)
  {
        Panel iconPanel = new Panel();
        PictureBox iconPic = new PictureBox();
        Label iconlabel = new Label();

        iconPanel.Name = domain;
        iconPic.Name = domain;
        iconlabel.Name = domain;

        iconPanel.MouseEnter += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Icon_MouseEnter(sender, e, iconPanel));
        iconPanel.MouseLeave += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Icon_MouseLeave(sender, e, iconPanel));
        iconPic.MouseEnter += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Icon_MouseEnter(sender, e, iconPanel));
        iconPic.MouseLeave += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Icon_MouseLeave(sender, e, iconPanel));
        iconlabel.MouseEnter += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Icon_MouseEnter(sender, e, iconPanel));
        iconlabel.MouseLeave += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Icon_MouseLeave(sender, e, iconPanel));

        iconPanel.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Icon_Clicked(sender, e, iconPanel));
        iconPic.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Icon_Clicked(sender, e, iconPanel));
        iconlabel.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Icon_Clicked(sender, e, iconPanel));
  }
```

Comment: I'm not used to C# but in JAVA I always use `hide()` when I click the confirmation button (I work with popups).

Comment: @SaintLike It's supposed to be already built in to the `MessageBox` in C#

Comment: The messagebox is part of Windows OS, so for it to not be working would mean something fundamental is wrong with your system. Are you certain the code isn't stuck in some kind of loop, re-displaying the messagebox after you click OK? Or perhaps you have made a call (elsewhere in your code) to a DllImport("user32.dll") method which is interfering with your messagebox? tbh: it's a very weird thing to be happening.

Comment: @911Rapid Do you have any breakpoints in your code somewhere? Also, try isolating the problem. Comment out the if statement  and see if the MessageBox performs correctly. Try another MessageBox elsewhere in your Form and see if it works.

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp If the Messagebox is placed in the load method of the form it works properly. But in this click event, it fails

Comment: Is the event actually firing at all? If you remove the if check does the MessageBox show?

Comment: @SimonPJ yes, the event is fired up and the message box is displayed. Please have a look at the question once again. i have edited the question for clarity

Comment: @911Rapid What is in the enter and leave events?

Comment: @SimonPJ Its just for changing the BackColor of Panels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was because of a timer that was running in the background to check if the taskbar gets resized. Once , i stopped the timer..the Messagebox worked properly